# C# messagebox equivalent in android

Tags: java, android

I want to create a function msgbox somewhat equivalent to C# or vb.net

The msgbox returns a True or False. If user clicked yes return true else false.

I tried to code like :

```
public boolean msgbox(String msg, String title )
{
    Boolean isclicked =false;
    if (title == null)
    {
        title = apinf.name; // If Title is null, then Set App Name as Title
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    add.setTitle(title);
    add.setMessage(msg);

    add.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            isclicked = true;

        }
    });
    add.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            isclicked=false;

        }
    });
    add.show();
    return isclicked;
}
```

I am going to use it like :

```
 if ( msgbox("Are you sure to close ?") == true)
 {
   // My code to do
 }
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: tip: Dont (try to) bring over programming habits from other languages

Comment: But i need function like this. Its not about programming habit. Is there any way to return boolean value from it ?

Comment: Android Developer Site: [Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) I found the Developer Site always a very good source of information and guidance. Also note the "best practices" Area ...

Comment: Of course there is a way, but in android things work differently. You will have to use callbacks, and not return a value from the function